# Problem involving Ergodic theorem and Markov Chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, ergodic

[image: This is the picture of one of the problems of my coursework.]

With regards to the question in the above picture and the markov chain drawn in the question, my query is **whether is it possible to conclude from Ergodic theorem that this Markov chain has an invariant stationary distribution** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a finite chain, in which case there is *always* a stationary distribution. In this case it looks like your chain is irreducible after removing vertex "4", so there's going to be a unique stationary distribution.

Comment: But why should I remove vertex "4", sir ? Does this mean that there is a problem with the question itself ?

Do I have to contact my professor to clarify about this ?

Comment: You're not removing vertex 4, it's just that vertex 4 only has outgoing paths hence it does not form a connected component with the rest of the vertices. The point is that in this case the stationary distribution will have a 0 component on vertex 4.

Comment: there is a path from 5 to 1 but not vice-versa, Then {1,2,3,5} is not a communicating class. Then how can i apply Ergodic theorem ?

Comment: Correct so in this case you can also remove 5.